# C#: System.IO.Exception. Why can the process not access the file? How do I allow the StreamWriter to access the file after it gets created?

Tags: c#, system.io.file

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace File_Dumping_Script
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rn = new Random();
            string fileName = Convert.ToString(rn.Next(1000));
            string path = ("C:\\Users\\taylo\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FileTesting\\" + fileName);
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                fileName = Convert.ToString(rn.Next(1000));
                path = ("C:\\Users\\taylo\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FileTesting\\" + fileName + ".txt");
            }
            File.CreateText(path);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
            Console.Write("Please enter a seed for the random numbers: ");
            int seed = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int written = 0;
            while (written != seed-1)
            {
                written = rn.Next(seed);
                sw.Write(" "+written);
                Console.WriteLine(written);
            }
            sw.Write("\n Process ended.");
            Console.WriteLine("Process complete.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I want this program to create a file with a random number for a name, and then write a bunch of random numbers to that file. I am currently facing a problem that the `File.CreateText();` is using the path, which means that the StreamWriter cannot create an object based off that path. Is there any way I can stop the `File.CreateText();` from using the file so the StreamWriter can access it instead?

Also, as a secondary, less important, problem, the files created are not text files, and the way I have tried to fix that with the `path = ("C:\\Users\\taylo\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FileTesting\\" + fileName);` doesn't make it a text file and nor does the `File.CreateText();` How do I make it a text file instead of a 'file'?

Thank you in advance,

Taylor

Comment: Side note, make your local instance of `Random` private, static and read-only outside of that main. So `private static readonly Random rn = new Random();` You want to keep a single instance of `Random` and *keep using the same instance* when you do `.Next` on that instance.

Comment: Alright, will do, thank you.

Comment: @zaggler: In a small program with a single `main` method, your suggestion is unlikely to provide any benefit.

Comment: File.CreateText() creates the file and returns a FileStream to interact with the file. There is no need to call File.CreateText() and _also_ initialize a StreamWriter, just use one or the other. [File.Create()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_Create_System_String_) ... and ... [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_)

Comment: I don't see a StreamReader in your code... do you mean the StreamWriter you open right after File.CreateText()? If so, as @quaabaam said, you don't need to open it. But also, you should close it when you are done writing by calling sw.Dispose() or a using-block.

Comment: To make it a text file, add `.txt`. to the end of the file name you specify. You're only adding `.txt` to the second line of code where you set the path, the first time you do it you don't specify the `.txt`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree to some extent, it may not provide any benefit in *this* program, but it does provide correct usage. What if the user decides to get a random number outside of main?

Comment: @zaggler: I wouldn't consider that idiomatic.  It's just as likely to be a class in a DI container set to Singleton scope, or merely a non-static member of an aggregate root (in this case, `Program`) that has lifetime scope.  Your scenario would propose accessing the Random object as `Program.RandomInstance` or something like that; a novel, if rather unorthodox approach.

Comment: @asgerhallas Yeah I meant StreamWriter, I was just messing around with StreamReaders earlier and I made a slight mistake. I'll try what quaabaam suggested. Thank you both.